A natural notion of "magnitude" for the elements in a real algebra
There are three 2D real algebras, up to isomorphism: the complex numbers, the split-complex numbers, and the dual numbers. Each of these has an associated notion of the "magnitude" - or rather, the squared magnitude - of a number:

For complex $a + bi$, we can use $a^2 + b^2$
For split-complex $a + bj$, we have $a^2 - b^2$
For dual $a + b\epsilon$, we have simply $a^2$

These sort of make sense, given the properties of these algebras: the complex numbers have a positive-definite quadratic form, the split numbers an indefinite one, and the dual numbers a positive-semidefinite one.
Each has the property of being continuous and multiplicative; it is a group homomorphism from the invertible elements of the algebra to $\Bbb R^*$.
Question: Is there some rigorous way to derive this notion of "magnitude" for an arbitrary real algebra? Does it have a name?
One thought: all of these algebras have $2 \times 2$ matrix representations, for which the determinant gives the above magnitude! This also gives sensible results for other algebras. Since the determinant has some unique properties regarding matrix multiplicativity, it would seem any multiplicative "magnitude" on an arbitrary algebra must be a function of the determinant.
So it does seem that there is a natural "magnitude" or "determinant" associated to any real algebra. Does this have a name? And perhaps some simpler, deeper way to derive it that doesn't involve representation theory?

If $K$ is any field, and $A$ is any finite-dimensional $K$-algebra, you can define a norm map $N:A\to K$ by $N(a)=\det(L_a)$ where $L_a: A\to A$ is the multiplication by $a$: $L_a(x)=ax$. This is always a multiplicative map if $A$ is associative.
But this is not a quadratic map: instead, if $A$ is $n$-dimensional, then the norm map is homogeneous of degree $n$. You also have a notion of reduced norm, which often lowers the degree, but not always.

Perfect! What is the reduced norm?

It's a little more delicate to properly define, I think the best reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203276. Basically it is the specialization of the constant coefficient of the minimal polynomial of a generic element.
